# android create drawable that is intersection between circle and rectangle

Tags: android

I would like to create an android xml drawable. That is the intersection between a circle and a rectangle.

Basically, i would like to have a rectangle. And then on the corner of this rectangle, draw a circle.

I would like to have the intersection of these two shapes to be used for a background.

This circle should have a radius slightly less than the height of the rectangle. So the intersection is not just 1/4 of the circle.

Is this something that can be created in a XML drawable in android?

Here is a very poorly drawn image using a trackpad..

The rectangle is what I would like to have for my background image. The shaded area should be able to have some color that I can change manually in the xml.
[image]

Comment: Any chance you could attach a sketch of what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `<vector>` drawable here.

```
<vector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="80dp"
    android:viewportWidth="48"
    android:viewportHeight="80">

    <path
        android:pathData="M48 0 a80 80 0 1 0 0.1 0z"
        android:fillColor="#caf"/>

</vector>
```

[image]

You can then apply this to your layout using the `android:background` attribute:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/circle_rect_intersection"
    ...>
```

You can even tint it (to get different colors) using `android:backgroundTint` on your root view.

[image]

Comment: Hey this looks super promising. But i just want to have the rectangle. Not really the whole circle.

Comment: @user1017674 I've updated my answer to correspond to your updated question

Comment: Do you mind adding a quick link where you drew the svg with such ease?

Comment: I just wrote them by hand. This resource (and just playing around in Androd Studio) is all I've ever used: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html (here, the https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands section is probably the most important).

Comment: Thanks man. I just read it. I didn't realize SVG was this simple. I have been using SVGs provided by my design team since forever and never understood what these numbers and letters mean!